# javascript properties of methods

Tags: javascript, oop

Is it possible in javascript to set properties inside methods?

For example

```
function Main() {

   this.method = function() {
      this.parameter = 'something_relevant'
   }
}

var p = new Main()
p.method()
console.log(p.method.parameter)
```

I tried this and it logs 'undefined'. Is it about scope?

Comment: That is because you `method` call is asynchronous, if you place the `console.log` inside `this.method` after the assignment it will work.

Comment: @Krister Andersson: There is nothing asynchronous here, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `method()` you're setting a property of the object on which the method is called rather than on the function object representing the method.

This shows the difference inside the method:

```
this.method = function() {
   this.parameter = 'abc'; // Set parameter on the object on which method() is called
   this.method.parameter = 'xyz'; // Set parameter on the object representing the method itself
};
```

This shows the difference in accessing the property after the method is called

```
p.method();
console.log(p.parameter); // Display property of the object p, equals 'abc'
console.log(p.method.parameter); // Display property of the function object representing method(), equals 'xyz'
```

You should decide whether you need a property on the function object or on `p` object. Note that the function object may be shared by a number of objects created by the `Main()` constructor. Hence it will behave in a manner somewhat similar to a static member in languages like C++ or Java.

If you intend to use property defined on the object, your code should look similar to this:

```
function Main() {

   this.method = function() {
      this.parameter = 'something_relevant'; // Set property on object on which method() is called.
   };
}

var p = new Main();
p.method();
console.log(p.parameter); // Read property from object p.
```

If you intend to use a property defined on the function object representing `method()`, your code should look similar to this:

```
function Main() {

   this.method = function() {
      this.method.parameter = 'something_relevant'; // Set property on function object representing method().
   };
}

var p = new Main();
p.method();
console.log(p.method.parameter); // Read property from the function object.
```

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer, basically i need a property that describes a method, so i can say that it is related to the 'class' (please forgive this word in a javascript context)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects basically, so just set it like you get it:

```
this.method = function() {

};

this.method.parameter = 'something_relevant';
```

Also, don't eliminate semicolons after expressions.